# Noun group order with adjective and の

Tags: grammar

To says "this is broth with strong umami" which order is right ? both ?
旨みの強い出汁です。or 強い旨みの出汁です。

Comment: Note that the の has different functions in both sentences. In 強い旨みの出汁, the の connects two noun, and it's the possessive particle. In 旨みの強い出汁, however, the の is functionally equivalent with が, and it's the same as 旨みが強い出汁. When used as a restrictive relative clause, の and が are interchangeable. You can easily find more info on the の-が conversion.

Comment: Your comment reply perfectly, now I totally understand. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, both are acceptable, but 旨みの強い出汁です sounds more natural. I guess this is because X味の強い as a whole is recognized as an adjective. So 酸味の強いジュース/苦みの強いコーヒー is more natural than 強い酸味のジュース/強い苦みのコーヒー.

On the other hand, I don’t think either 屋根の赤い家/赤い屋根の家 is particularly natural (Or even the latter may be more natural).